# Table designing - OR query vs separate table

Tags: sql, database-design

I need some help in table designing and not sure what would be the best option. Basically I need to store who all are having permission to use any particular resource. A resource can be used by different type of entities and its instances. For example here is simple way of representing the same

1. I have two different types of Entity, EntityType1 and EntityType2
   (in my case this should be really small number not more than 10)
2. We can have multiple instances of each entity, which we can identify
   with EntityId
3. We can have different resource type R1, R2, R3..etc
4. Each resource type can have multiple instances

[image]

There is another requirement where I can say all entities of particular type has access to one particular resource instance. Something similar to * in the EntityId column. I'll have index on entityId as well so wanted to keep it as INT type only. Note that i can have entry for all and specific entity together.

I can think of two options

1. I will choose some Invalid EntityId to represent all entities (*) like 0, -1 or NULL and then use OR clause to return what all resources are permissible for a particular entityId. Ex: `EntityType = 'EntityType1' and (EntityId = 1 or EntityId = 0)`
2. Create separate table and add new entry to indicate all entity permission and then join the table to return the data.

Can somebody tell me which options would be preferable here or any other suggestion, I am more inclined towards option 2 as we don't need to store some invalid value in the table to indicate something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a table of entities, which would seem to have columns for `EntityId` and `EntityType`.

You should have a table of resources, which would have `ResourceId` and `ResourceType`.

Then, it sounds like you want two additional tables:

- A mapping table between entities and resources.
- A mapping table between entity types and resources.

I would start with this set of relationships.  Using wildcards in tables can result in `join` conditions with `or`s, which can really slow things down.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, if i understand correctly option(1) with OR condition will make things slow down, so its better to split into multiple tables?

Comment: @Nikhil . . . It could.  There may be ways around that.  But I would start with modeling the data the way that you describe it, with relationships both at the entity and the type level.